# jQuery: Copy HTML and output it into xmp

Tags: jquery

What seamed like a simple concept in my head doesn't seam to work, what I am trying to build is a simple jQuery "app" where a user can change styles of some objects using a class toggle and then once the user is happy with the result they can output the HTML so they can copy it and email it to me.

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kellyhawker/94tLL4e7/1/)

So I found out how to clone HTML and output the clone into a xmp tag however it just makes a duplicate rather than outputting the raw HTML which to me doesn't make much sense since its inside the xmp tag, there is something i'm missing or don't understand.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

$('.toggleSwitch').click(function(){
  $('.redSquare').toggleClass('toggleBorder');
  $(this).toggleClass("on");
});

$('.output').click(function(){
  var $code = $('.container').clone();
  $('.outputCon').html($code);
});

});
```

Comment: You want to appear only one square in the xmp?

Comment: I just want plain text / raw HTML of the red square to appear in the xmp tag, usually an xmp tag (or pre and code tags) just display plain text on the front end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of:

```
$('.output').click(function(){
  var $code = $('.container').clone();
  $('.outputCon').html($code);
});
```

Use:

```
   $('.output').click(function(){
      var $code = $('.container').html();
      $('.outputCon').text($code);
    });
```